# loopback: Is there any model relation that automatically creates related model

Tags: model, relation, loopback

I have a question with loopback.io

i'm controlling two models, Room and Power.
Room model is a space like chatting room.
And Power model is a table contains privilege for room members.
For example if roomA has two member's privilege, 'reader' and 'writer', and roomB has two member's privilege, 'writer' and 'commneter', then Power table have four records.

```
Power model:
id   room     privilege
1    roomA    reader
2    roomA    writer
3    roomB    reader
4    roomB    commenter
```

So what I want to do is when create a room it automatically also creates reader privilege for that room as default value.

For example, in boot script I create a room like this.

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    Room.create({
        roomName:'roomA'
    }, function(err, room) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Then in room table there is roomA and in power table there is {roomA, reader}.

How can I do this?